# Java For loop executes only one time

Tags: java, for-loop, binaryfiles

For some reason my for loop only executes once. It goes through the first iteration, but then gets stuck at the beginning. This is what the loop looks like.

```
for (int i = 0; i < z.length()/4; i++) {
        m.writeInt(z.readInt());
}
for (int i = 0; i < o.length()/4; i++) {
        m.writeInt(o.readInt());
}
```

These are two seperate loops

This is a radix sorting merge. But with binary files. If that helps. I think it might have something to do with calling the method z.readInt() within m.writeInt()

m. o, and z are binary files filled with integers 
z.length() return 16, so there are 4 integers in the files because each integer is 4 bytes. So z.Length()/4 = 4.
The loop is supposed to execute 4 times

Comment: How does it stuck? Does the execution terminate, do you get an exception or does it do nothing?

Comment: what is z in the loop.can u please specify its initialization and declaration.

Comment: printing the length of z and o before and during the loop might help you see why it's only running once

Comment: m, o and z, are binary files

Comment: Why only read a quarter of the file?

Comment: I am reading the amount of integers in the file. Since each integer is 4 bytes. z.length() is 16. (4 Ints in file * 4 bytes per int) So 16 / 4(bytes) = 4

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "gets stuck at the beginning".  What exactly happens after the first iteration?  And what are the **Java types** of `z`, `m`, and `o`?  What is the value of `z.position()` *before* the first loop, if such a method exists?

Comment: The loop executes once. When it goes back to the beginning of the loop, it stays at the begninning without going inside the loop. It stays at for(int i = 0; i < z.length()/4; i++) until the argument is true. SO i increments without going in the loop

Comment: Z,m,o and binary files. and z.position is 0. So it starts reading from the beginning of the file

Comment: "binary file" is not a Java type.  What is the object type?  Paste the variable declarations so we can see.  If we don't know the types, we can't investigate the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

z.length/4 performs integer division, so if you have z=5, then it'll return 1. This is likely to be your problem, but we'd have to see a little more to be sure. (for example, what are o and z?)